# Snow leopard Full Install?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, installation, osx-leopard

I have MBP 17" Unibody with Leopard pre-installed. I'm planning to buy Snow Leopard ($29) but I wonder if I'll be able to format my disk and install clean copy of Snow Leopard since its an 'upgrade' pack?

To reiterate, can I just upgrade from leopard to snow leopard or I can also install a fresh copy of snow leopard?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googled it, and yes, its possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is no such thing as an "upgrade" disc for Apple, I've always been able to use upgrade discs to do the full install.  Actually even with Windows 7 there are hacks on how to get it to do a full install :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.